# An instructor retrieves the student who are enrolled in the course he/she teaches

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a simple website that helps students and instructors in universities.

I am facing a problem about the following query:
An instructor retrieves the students' IDs and names who are enrolled in the course he/she teaches.

I have the following tables, followed by their fields:
Enrollment (CourseCode - StudentID - Grade)
Studnet (ID - Name)

As you can see the only connector between the two tables is the student ID.

The code that I wrote is

```
<?
session_start();
$COCODE = $_SESSION['GlobalCode'];

$result11 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Enrollment WHERE CourseCode = '$COCODE' ") ;

$row11 = mysql_fetch_array($result11);
$StID = $row11['StudentID'];
$result22 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Student where StudentID= '$StID' ") ;
echo "<table border cellpadding=3>";

while($row123 = mysql_fetch_array($result22)) 
 { 
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>".$row123['ID']."</td> ";
 echo "<td>".$row123['Name']."</td> ";
 echo "</tr>";
 } 

echo "</table>"; 
?>
```

What I am trying to do is to retrieve the course code from the Enrollment table and then retrieving the students names through the ID.

The problem is that I got the following message:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource
```

I hope you can help me solving the problem.

Thanks

Comment: Be careful that you don't open yourself to SQL injection issues.  Learn to do prepared queries with PDO to avoid this problem entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to narrow down which of the queries is causing the problem? That would be your first step. Some other pointers:

1. you need to check that each SQL query is successful and returning a valid value before using it in the next query... otherwise that query will cause an error.
2. Try using: `mysql_query ($your_query) or die ('Error: '.mysql_error ());` for each query for a more detailed error message. (for debugging only, not for production)

Answer (score 0):

That error usually means there's something wrong with your query, or perhaps you are not connected to your database. If its the first problem, try changing your query to this:

```
$result11 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Enrollment` WHERE `CourseCode` = '$COCODE' ");
```

Otherwise, check your database connection.

Comment: The connection is fine and I changed the query and the problem is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved it.

I did the following changes:

```
$result11 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Enrollment WHERE CourseCode = '$InstID' ") or die ('Error: '.mysql_error ());

echo "<table border cellpadding=3>";

while($row11 = mysql_fetch_array($result11))
{
$StID = $row11['StudentID'];
$result22 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Students where ID = '$StID' ") or die ('Error: '.mysql_error ()); 
while($row123 = mysql_fetch_array($result22)) 
{ 
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$row123['ID']."</td> ";
echo "<td>".$row123['Name']."</td> ";
echo "</tr>";
} 
}
echo "</table>"; 

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Thanks